# Timer - to count Time

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, timertask

I am making a quiz application, in which I want to show the time used by the user while playing a session of game. It should be in format HH:MM:SS starting from 00:00:00 till he selects the answer. Timer should be updating every second  while user is playing each second. Also, I want to pause the timer while next question is loading. I am not able to understand how to do this. Right now I am able to fetch current time by this code.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                final String startTime = timeformat.format(c.getTime());
                Play.timer_box.setText(""+startTime);
```

It just display whatever the current time is in the box in right format. But not able to understand how to achieve what i want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just show the time using calendar,you have to write the logic

1. Start counter when activity/fragment is resumed till user selects
   answer
2. Stop it once user selects the ans,ans start it again once next
   question (activity/fragment is loaded)
3. Convert counter to the time format you want to display,you will need
   a logic for the same